# xml serialization to string with whitespaces

Tags: c#, xml

I have some data that I want to serialize to an XML string, in memory, preserving white spaces.I tried this:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string NormalField {get; set;}
        public string WhitespaceField {get; set;}
    }

    string GetXml(List<MyClass> data)
    {
        string xml = "";

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
        using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ser.Serialize(xmlStream, data);
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlStream.Position = 0;
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
            xml = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
        }

        return xml;
    }

    void Execute()
    {
        List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
        list.Add(new MyClass { NormalField = "a", WhitespaceField = "   456" });
        string xml = GetXml(list);
    }
```

However the whitespaces are not preserved. Specifically one field in my data is a string with leading spaces that I want preserved but it doesn't happen.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you need to reset the Position property of the stream before loading into the XmlDocument? Also, try looking in the document _before_ you look at `OuterXml`. In other words, make sure it's not `OuterXml` stripping the whitespace.

Comment: How aboud posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so that we can copy&paste your code and try to answer.

Comment: I added a fully functional example.

Comment: And I just realized it actually works, only the XML visualizer in VS showed wrong data, with no leading spaces. The text visualizer shows correct data.